# Vue.js multiple instances of same component issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have created a vue component for selecting photos. When the user clicks any photo the id of the photo will be assigned to a hidden input field inside the component.

Now I have used this component twice on the same page with different data. The problem is when I click on the photo of one component the value of the input field of both the components gets updated. I am using vue.js version *2.1.10*
Here is the simplified version of my component.

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" :name="inputName" :value="currentSelectedPhoto.id">
    <div v-for="photo in photos">
        <div v-on:click="updateSelectedPhoto(photo)">
            <img :src="photo.photo_url" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Component

```
export default {
    props: {
        ...
    },
    methods: {
        getPhotos(){
            ...
        },
        updateSelectedPhoto(photo){
            this.currentSelectedPhoto = photo;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how I am using it in html

```
<div>
    <div>
        Profile Photo
        <photo-selector
            photos="{{ $photos }}"
            input-name="profile_photo_id"
            >
        </photo-selector>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        Cover Photo
        <photo-selector
            photos="{{ $otherPhotos }}"
            input-name="cover_photo_id"
            >
        </photo-selector>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example? I don't see that behavior when I try (also Vue 2.1.10): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWVYpm

Comment: Hi @Matt I have created a pen https://codepen.io/sajjad26/pen/qmVYLv

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on your [codepen](https://codepen.io/sajjad26/pen/qmVYLv) sample, it's because you are sharing the state object between the two:

```
const initalState = {
  selectedPhoto: null
};

const PhotoSelector = Vue.extend({
  data: () => {
    return initalState
  },
```

Vue *mutates* the initial state object (by wrapping it in reactive getters etc), so you need to have `data()` return a fresh state object for the instance to use:

```
data: () => {
  return {
    selectedPhoto: null
  };
},
```