# Multiple instance of same component are not independent in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

I'm working on a component to handle Image uploading on VueJS and I'm facing an issue with independancy of each components.

parent.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ImageUploader />
        <ImageUploader />
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import ImageUploader from '@/components/ImageUploader.vue';

    @Component({
        components: {
            ImageUploader
        }
    })
    export default class Credits extends Vue {

    }
</script>
```

ImageUploader.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input v-if="input" type='hidden' :name='inputName' :value='imageValue' class='edition_input'/>
        <label>{{ label }}</label>
        <div class="file-selector">
            <img :src="imageChanged ? imageRender : imageValue" style="width: 100%; height: auto;"/>
            <label for="image" class="btn btn-outline-blue">{{ imageName }}</label>
            <input type="file" name="image" @change="processFile" id="image" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Prop, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';

    @Component
    export default class ImageUploader extends Vue {

        @Prop({ default: "" })
        label!: string;

        @Prop({ default: "" })
        defaultValue!: string;

        @Prop({ default: false })
        input!: boolean;

        @Prop({ default: "" })
        inputName!: string;
        
        image;
        imageRender: string|ArrayBuffer|null = "";
        imageName = "Fichier";
        imageValue: string|ArrayBuffer|null = "";
        imageChanged = false;

        mounted(){
            this.imageValue = this.defaultValue != '' ? this.baseAPIPath + this.defaultValue : "";
        }

        processFile(event){
            this.image = event.target.files[0];
            this.imageName = this.image.name;

            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                this.imageRender = e.target != null ? e.target.result : null;
                this.imageChanged = true;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.image);

            this.$emit("update:imageName", this.imageName);
            this.$emit("update:image", this.image);
        }

        @Watch("imageName")
        imageNameChange(){
            this.imageValue = "uploads/img/" + this.imageName;
        }

        get baseAPIPath(){
            return process.env.VUE_APP_API;
        }

    }
</script>
```

The issue is that if I select a file with the second ImageUploader, the file is showed in the first one. In other terms, both components are clearly not independents...
Is there a way to make each components state local ?

I searched for solutions and [this problem description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50272331/vue-js-components-not-independent-of-each-other) is pretty similar but the solution didn't work (or I didn't implemented it correctly, it's possible...)

Thanks !

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43833036/vue-js-multiple-instances-of-same-component-issue

Comment: But how can I handle data(){} function with class components ? Don't exactly understand this point as data are declared as properties of class. Also, because they are properties of the class, they should not be shared between multiple instances of the class...

Comment: tried `data(){ return {} }` format but still without success... My data are still shared between the two components